# How do I open SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using eclipse and when I try to open SceneBuilder through it, it gives me the following message:
ScreenShot of problem:

[image]

I have already embedded the pathway of SceneBuilder in preferences so that's not the problem.

Any idea how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse > Preferences > JavaFX**

**Path: /Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOs/scenebuilder-launcher.sh**

Comment: "/Applications/SceneBuilder.app", I already had this as the path so it didn't change anything.

Comment: @RayaanRizwan I've edited my answer this will solve the problem

Comment: Go to /Applications/SceneBuilder.app and check whats going on in there because every forum I've read says the exact same thing. I think its called something else like SceneBuilder2.app or something

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me to do.

Comment: Did you check if there's a .app file in te directory you're pointing to?

Comment: Yeah its there.

Comment: No problem.. :)